# Adding a Data Connection in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, database-connection

My trouble is, as the title suggests, about adding a data connection in Visual Studio 2010. Whenever I try to add a connection using the Server Explorer, the application seems to crash and restart itself automatically. This happens whenever I try to provide the server name for the wizard, either by typing it manually or trying to pick it from the dropdown list for the servers.

I tried a re-install already, removing all components along the way, but it wasn't to be. The error message I get is "An error occurred and Visual Studio will close now", so, it's not helping me much, either.

I'd appreciate any sorts of ideas, no matter how slight the chances of spotting the trouble from the get go might be.
Thanks in advance to everyone.

~Can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That isn't normal behaviour, no... It works fine for me, with VS2010 and SQL 2008R2.

If reinstall of VS dies nothing to fix it, then you need to start looking at other external apps - it may be SQL that causes the problem.
So: try via SSMS and see if that works.
Try connecting to an Access or SQLCE database instead and see if that works.

Of the problem is only SQL/VS then if the SQL instance is on the same PC try uninstalling VS and SQL, then install SQL first, then VS on top of that - I've had problems in the past with install order for the combination, since VS installs is own 'micro' SQL system if it doesn't find the full Monty.

Of all else fails, wipe the disk, reinstall windows, then SQL, then VS!